# How to get only the device name and the free space percentage WITHOUT the property field?

Tags: powershell, command, powershell-remoting

### I have a command that returns the DeviceID and the free space percentage as follows:

```
    $devices= Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "Drivetype=3" | Select-Object  DeviceID, @{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}}
    Write-Output $devices
```

---

### The output is good, as follows:

```
DeviceID       : C:
Free (%)       :   33 %
PSComputerName : MIKAELCOMP
RunspaceId     : c2b02166-4e08-4e90-b8f5-5defafa20ac9

DeviceID       : D:
Free (%)       :   22 %
PSComputerName : MIKAELCOMP
RunspaceId     : c2b02166-4e08-4e90-b8f5-5defafa20ac9
```

---

### HOWEVER, I need the output to be like this:

```
C: 33%
D: 22%
```

---

As you see, without the description in the first column.

Any way to do that?

(also, I don't know why I'm getting the last two fields: PSComputerName and RunspaceId).

THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [string format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) (`-f`) for this:

```
$devices | ForEach-Object {
    "{0} {1}" -f $_.DeviceID,$_.'Free (%)'.Trim()
}
```

`Trim()` is used to remove the preceding and trailing spaces you may have for your percentage values. `TrimStart()` can be used to only remove preceding spaces. `TrimEnd()` can be used to only remove trailing spaces.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I want...Thank you!

Comment: @Smorkster, I've changed the wording in the answer.